# Artinian ring is Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, alternative-proof, noetherian, artinian

I was trying to proof that any Artinian ring is a Noetherian ring, but I found on the Web that the proof is non trivial. 
However I have a proof I hope you can help me in finding errors.

Let $R $ be a non Noetherian ring, or there exists an ideal $I \lhd R$ such that $d_R (I)=\infty $ where $$d_R (I)=min (\{n\in \mathbb N | \exists a_1,...,a_n\in I : I=\displaystyle \sum _{1\leq i\leq n} Ra_i\} \cup \{\infty\}).$$
I want to show that any such ideal contains an ideal non finitely generated and thus I can create a non stationary descending chain of ideals, and show $R$ is not Artinian. 
Now let $G=\{a_i\}_{i\in J}$ be a generator system for $I$ and suppose it is minimal, or $\forall j\in J,\ I=\displaystyle  \sum_{a\in G} Ra \supsetneq \displaystyle \sum _{a\in G\setminus \{a_j\}} Ra$.
Thus, $J $ is infinite because $d_R  (I)=\infty $. Let now $J'\subseteq J $ such that $J'=\{a_{k_i}\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is countable (its existence is assured by the minimality of cardinality $\aleph _0$ in infinite sets).
Now let be $R\rhd I_1=\displaystyle \sum_ {a\in G\setminus \{a_{k_1}\}}\subseteq I.$ Now, if $I=I_1$, then $G $ is not minimal. Thus $I_1\subsetneq I $. Let now $G_1$ be a  generator minimal system for $I_1$: $G_1$ is infinite because otherwise $I=I_1+a_{k_1} $ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that every ideal has a minimal generating set. This is not necessarily true for non-Noetherian rings, so you would need to justify why it is true for Artinian rings.

Comment: Thus may I consider a non-finitely generated ideal constructed as follows: let $I$ be the ideal such that $d_R (I)=\infty $. For $k\in \mathbb N $ be $a_{k+1}\in I$ such that $a_{k+1}\in I\setminus \displaystyle \sum _ {i=1}^k Ra_i $ and $a_1\in I\setminus {0}$. Be $\mathfrak I=\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{\infty} Ra_i $ and $\mathfrak I_1$ constructed like before.

Comment: @Blumer Even then, $\mathfrak{I}$ may not have a minimal generating set., as it could be that $Ra_1<Ra_2<Ra_3<\dots$.